# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Util\Configuration::getExtensionConfiguration()

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.6

I am trying to follow the instructions here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/testing. On the Environment section here what I did.

```
php artisan env --env=testing
```

and then run

```
phpunit
```

but after that, this message show up

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Util\Configuration::getExtensionConfiguration() in /mnt/c/projects/www/janicalizdotcom/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:953
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/c/projects/www/janicalizdotcom/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(153): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(195): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite), Array, true)
#2 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(148): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#3 /usr/bin/phpunit(34): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/c/projects/www/janicalizdotcom/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 953
```

What is that mean? and what I should do about it?

I have no idea since its the first time running laravel test

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If just `phpunit` works that means that you have a global installation of PHPUnit. You probably want to use `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead.

Comment: I thought i will be looking vendor/bin/phpunit instead of typing it in a command